# PhantomJSCloud How to use mouse click options

Tags: javascript, php, json, phantomjs, php-phantomjs

I would like to know and understand how I can add javascript code to my current code in order to perform actions such as a click on a page that I loaded using phantomjscloud using their api.

Here is my current code, it works and returns the HTML code of the page correctly but not the one after the click:

PHP :

```
<?php    

    $apikey = "";
    
    $url = 'http://PhantomJScloud.com/api/browser/v2/'.$apikey.'/';
    $payload = file_get_contents ( 'request.json' );
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => $payload
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }
    var_dump($result);
    
    ?>
```

Json :

```
{
    "pages":[
        {
            "url": "http://myurl.com",
            "content": null,
            "urlSettings": {
                "operation": "GET",
                "encoding": "utf8",
                "headers": {},
                "data": null
            },
            "renderType": "HTML",
            "outputAsJson": false,
            "requestSettings": {
                "ignoreImages": false,
                "disableJavascript": false,
                "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/534.34 PhantomJS/2.0.0 (PhantomJsCloud.com/2.0.1)",
                "xssAuditingEnabled": false,
                "webSecurityEnabled": false,
                "resourceWait": 15000,
                "resourceTimeout": 35000,
                "maxWait": 35000,
                "waitInterval": 1000,
                "stopOnError": false,
                "resourceModifier": [],
                "customHeaders": {},
                "clearCache": false,
                "clearCookies": false,
                "cookies": [{
                        "domain": "",
                        "httponly": true,
                        "name": ".AspNetCore.Cookies",
                        "path": "/",
                        "secure": false,
                        "value": ""
                    }],
                "deleteCookies": []
            },
            "suppressJson": [
                "events.value.resourceRequest.headers",
                "events.value.resourceResponse.headers",
                "frameData.content",
                "frameData.childFrames"
            ],
            "renderSettings": {
                "quality": 70,
                "pdfOptions": {
                    "border": null,
                    "footer": {
                        "firstPage": null,
                        "height": "1cm",
                        "lastPage": null,
                        "onePage": null,
                        "repeating": "%pageNum%/%numPages%"
                    },
                    "format": "letter",
                    "header": null,
                    "height": null,
                    "orientation": "portrait",
                    "width": null
                },
                "clipRectangle": null,
                "renderIFrame": null,
                "viewport": {
                    "height": 1280,
                    "width": 1280
                },
                "zoomFactor": 1,
                "passThroughHeaders": false
            },
            "scripts": {
                "domReady": [],
                "loadFinished": []
            }
        }
    ],
    "proxy":false
}
```

I think I need to add javascript code in the JSON in "scripts" but I don't know how to go about it, thank you

Comment: I added this to my JSON code, but I still can't get what I'm trying to do, I don't know if the coordinates of the click are bad (if so how can I find them) or if the code is not working properly.

Here is the line I added :  "overseerScript":"page.mouse.click(60,220);",

Comment: Or is it possible to click on a specific text on the page using the overseerscript ? I searched everywhere but I can't find a solution